# Paste linked single excel cell into powerpoint text

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am trying to copy a single excel cell like this:

[image]

into an existing powerpoint slide, within an existing cell like this:
[image]

What I tried to do is "Paste special", paste link in the picture below. Note that I needed to drag it there manually, which is already unwanted.

[image]

But the result is a "fake cell" that I have to drag manually in the right position and is not within the regular text, as I would need. Does anyone know a better solution to obtain the result of automation like in the second picture?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim xlsApp As Object
Dim xlsWB As Object

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "FileName.xlsx")

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Subtitle").TextFrame.TextRange = "The excel sheet content should appear here within this text: " & xlsWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

xlsWB.Save
xlsWB.Close
xlsApp.Quit

Set xlsWB = Nothing
Set xlsApp = Nothing
```

You can change the Slide Index. You can customise the name of the shape via Selection Pane.
Use `vbNewLine` to add a break between the line.

Use `For Loops` to automate this.